# how to write a elisp function like this

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a `elisp` function like this:

```
(setq lst '(("abc" . "c") ("cde" . "f")))
(foo "a" lst) ;=>"c"
(foo "b" lst) ;=>"c"
(foo "c" lst) ;=>"c"
(foo "d" lst) ;=>"f"
```

I know if the first string is same as the key string I can use `assoc`.

```
(setq lst '(("a" . "c") ("d" . "f")))
(cdr (assoc "a" lst)) ;= "c"
(cdr (assoc "d" lst)) ;= "f"
```

I could enable the function by writing the `lst` separately, but I don't think it's the best way to do.

```
(setq lst '(("a" . "c") ("b" . "c") ("c" . "c")
            ("c" . "f") ("d" . "f") ("f" . "f")
            ))
```

Can someone help me how to write the function like `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no elisp expert, but this works. Or ask on [emacs.stackexchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com).

```
 (defun foo (ch lst)
   (when lst
     (if (string-match-p ch (car (car lst)))
         (cdr (car lst))
       (foo ch (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't use the function you made. Can you show me a example?

Comment: you just use your examples, eg `(foo "a" lst)` produces `"c"`.

Comment: oh, thanks! I did something wrong last time.